# Not getting upvotes on accepted answer after rep cap

Tags: bug, reputation

IIRC accepted answers are fully immune to the rep cap limit.

I have reached the rep cap before and don't remember not getting the upvotes reflected on my reputation after I reached the limit, but this time I stopped from receiving the upvotes on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53945490/how-to-assert-that-a-constexpr-if-else-clause-never-happen/53945549#53945549) after I reached the rep cap.

Is this the expected behavior, I mean, are accepted answers subjected to rep cap or not? if not, what can I do to get the upvotes reflected in my reputation?

Up to now, the expected rep on that answer will be 165, but I only see 135

Answer (score 4):

> IIRC accepted answers are fully immune to the rep cap limit.

Where did you get that from?

The only thing that's *immune* against rep cap is acceptance of your answer (+15 rep), nothing more nothing less.

Comment: Thanks, I'm clear now.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this the expected behavior, I mean, are accepted answers subjected to rep cap or not?

Yes. Accepted answers aren't immune to the reputation cap. Only the 15 reputation points you get for when someone accepts your answer isn't affected by that.

> if not, what can I do to get the upvotes reflected in my reputation?

Sadly, nothing. That's how the reputation cap works.